# Insert value in postgres with type PATH

Tags: postgresql, gis, sql-insert

Hello I have created a table with a column type PATH as above (following the Postgres documentation)

```
CREATE TABLE public.geometry_polyline_volume
(
    id          serial not null primary key,
    distance    float not null,
    height      float not null,
    coordinates path not null
);
```

Trying to insert the above values as a row

```
INSERT INTO public.geometry_polyline_volume(id, distance, height, coordinates)
VALUES (2,  500, 0, path((15.878137629895164,47.08306448089695), (15.56169808311181,47.219041634920686), (15.267442604782124,47.4201665137259), (15.092631384557304,47.71366328136526), (15.234428926980286,47.95865145177352)));
```

I am taking the following error

> Message    : ERROR: column "coordinates" is of type path but
>   expression is of type record

Comment: The answer is here -> https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/349653/157588

Answer (score 0):

Use the extension "PostGIS", after installation its a pretty straight forward gig:

and then insert using this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (geom) VALUES (
  ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)', 26910)
);
```

Hope this helps.